# Is it possible to prevent Tachyon from writing to underFS?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, alluxio

Is it possible to prevent Tachyon from writing to underFS ?
I would like it to store data just on memory drive and omit writing them to underFS. Is it possible or supported ?

Regards,
Mike

Answer (score 2):

By default Tachyon only writes to Tachyon space (in memory), as you can see in the configuration description `tachyon.user.file.readtype.default` at http://tachyon-project.org/documentation/Configuration-Settings.html

But you still need to configure `underFS`, because there is information such as journals to be persisted for fault tolerance.

Comment: As far as I understand, if this property is set to CACHE_PROMOTE, the file will be written to underFS : "Default write type when creating Tachyon files. Valid options are `CACHE_PROMOTE` (move data to highest tier if already in Tachyon storage, write data into highest tier of local Tachyon if data needs to be read from under storage), `CACHE` (write data into highest tier of local Tachyon if data needs to be read from under storage), `NO_CACHE` (no data interaction with Tachyon, if the read is from Tachyon data migration or eviction will not occur)."